# Azure "blobService is not defined" error with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

Here is my node codes in order to connect Azure Blob Storage and upload base64 photo to recieve url link for the photo. Codes are based on Azure tutorial but somehow my AccountName and AccountKey fails. I could not figure out how to set up my createBlobService variable.My AccountName and AccountKey's are just simple strings ie. "Product", "Base64KeyProvidedByAzure"

Any help please?

Account name, account key and container names are just dummy strings here.

```
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService('AccountName', 'AccountKey');


        blobService.createContainerIfNotExists('containerName', {
            publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
        }, function(error, result, response) {
            if (!error) {
                // if result = true, container was created.
                // if result = false, container already existed.
                var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                    AccessPolicy: {
                        Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
                    }
                };
                var sharedAccessSignatureToken = blobSvc.generateSharedAccessSignature('ContainerName', req.params.filename, sharedAccessPolicy);
                var sharedBlobService = azure.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobSvc.host, sharedAccessSignatureToken);

                sharedBlobService.createBlockBlobFromText('eats', req.params.name, req.params.file,
                    {
                        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
                        contentEncoding: 'base64'
                    },

                    function(error, result, response) {
                    if (error) {
                        res.send(error);
                        return;
                    }


                    var msg = "Photo Uploaded successfully";
                    helpers.success(res, next, msg, 200);
                    return next();
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: are you able to generate a valid SAS token and if yes is sharedBlobService  getting created properly. as such this is a straight forward flow , i don't see an issue here. it could be some small issue only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a blob service instance and assign to `blobSvc` in line 1:

> `var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService('AccountName', 'AccountKey');`

However, you used `blobService` to call functions in SDK. So it threw `blobService is not defined` exception.

Comment: If it is helpful to you, you can mark it as the answer. Thank you.